# Content of variable changing after read in ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am new to ruby (started yesterday) and I'm playing a bit with sinatra to build an API. I encountered an issue which left me without clue:

```
post '/login' do
    if request.body.read.length == 0
       halt 400 # bad request 
    else
        body = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
    end
end
```

When I executed this code, I had an error because I tried to parse an empty string with `body = JSON.parse(request.body.read)`. In fact, I had to save `request.body.read` in another variable to use it twice (or more), because it's like `request.body` gets "consumed" after the first use.

This reminds me of borrows with rust, but here I wasn't expecting that and can't express it on google to find any documentation. *Can anyone explain me what happened and why `request.body` is readable only one time?*

For people who have the same problem (we never know), here's the fix:

```
post '/login' do
    body = request.body.read

    if body.length == 0
        halt 400 # bad request
    else
        body_json = JSON.parse(body)
    end
end
```

I heard about IO objects but I still can't go further in my researches.

Comment: You need at least one more tag, as what you've posted is not pure Ruby.

Comment: This is covered (admittedly lightly) here: http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`request.body` is an input stream.

Streams are a basic data structure in computing where data is provided in sequence and has to be consumed in sequence. For example data sent over the internet is a stream.

Stream processing is very powerful because it allows you process data that is bigger than a machine's memory, for example movies on Netflix are streamed to your computer so they never have to store the entire movie but the current frames only.

Typically streams can only be read once. If you want to access the stream data more than once you have to buffer it. Which is what you're doing with `body = request.body.read`, well done!

Some streams are rewindable. As it happens the `request.body` in Sinatra is rewindable, so you can rewind it to the begin and read it all again.

```
request.body.read
request.body.rewind
request.body.read # => returns the content again
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll read more about streams and more particularly in ruby, I think that's the term that was missing in my google queries. Happy new year!

Comment: You're welcome! They are not always called streams in Ruby. Good starting points are `IO` and `Enumerable` and `Enumerable::Lazy`